# How to patch a macro with control sequences using regexpatch

Tags: expl3, xpatch, l3regex

I have partial success patching a macro with `regexpatchcmd`. I would like to patch a macro that calls another macros. The purpose is that every command in the patched macro becomes inside `\string` and `\ttfamily` macros. It works except when the macro contains `@` symbol.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{regexpatch}
\tracingxpatches
\begin{document}
\def\testone{test \Test \tESt \@Test \Te@st}
\def\testtwo{\Test \tESt \@Test \Te@st}
\regexpatchcmd*{\testone}{\c{[a-zA-Z@]*}}{\c{begingroup}\c{ttfamily}\c{string}\0\c{endgroup}}{}{}
\regexpatchcmd*{\testtwo}{\c{[a-zA-Z@]*}}{\c{begingroup}\c{ttfamily}\c{string}\0\c{endgroup}}{}{}
\show\testone
\show\testtwo
\testone -- \testtwo
\end{document}
```

Both commands are patchable (according to `\trackingxpatches`, so no problem with this). The output of `\show\testone` is:

```
> \testone=macro:
->test \begingroup \ttfamily \string \Test \endgroup
\begingroup \ttfamily \string \tESt \endgroup
\begingroup \ttfamily \string \@\endgroup
Test
\begingroup \ttfamily \string \Te \endgroup @st
```

When processing `\@Test`, why we have `\@` inside the group *but* `Test` outside? so why the matching for the regex stops at `@`?

A similar situation happens patching `\Te@st`: only `\Te` is matched but `@st` doesn't. In this case, the scanning for the regex stops before `@`.

The `\testtwo` macro shows a different behavior. Thw following lines are the output of the `\show\testtwo` line on MWE:

```
> \testtwo=macro:
->\Test \tESt
\begingroup \ttfamily \string \@\endgroup Test
\begingroup \ttfamily \string \Te \endgroup @st.
```

It behaves the same respecting the `@` symbol. The difference between `\testone` and `\testtwo` macros is the prepended `test` word. Without that word (like in `\testtwo`) the regular expression written does not matches the first two commands (`\Test` and `\tESt`). Why?

I would like to understand the mistake in the regex.

As a side note, `regexpatch.sty` loads `l3regex.sty` and a warning is issued to use `expl3` instead of `l3regex`, so `regexpatch.sty` should be updated to use `expl3`.

Comment: For bug reports, you should tell the package's current maintainer or author.

Comment: The warning will disappear as soon as possible. It is due to `l3regex` having been recently incorporated in the L3 kernel.

Answer (score 4):

TeX works on tokens. Your `\testone` macro has a replacement text consisting of the seventeen tokens

```
t•e•s•t• •\Test•\tESt•\@•T•e•s•t• •\Te•@•s•t
```

(I use `•` for separating tokens). The tokens matching your search expression are numbers 6, 7, 8 and 14.

It would be different if the definition *and* the replacement happen when `@` is a letter, because in this case the tokens are just nine and, for instance `\Te@st` is considered a single token at definition time.

However, the replacement must be performed also when `@` is a letter, or the rebuilding of the macro would not succeed (this limitation might be lifted in a future version of `regexpatch`).

Note that you can make a much shorter search expression:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{regexpatch}

\newcommand{\stringify}[1]{\texttt{\string#1}}

\begin{document}

\makeatletter
\def\testone{test \Test \tESt \@Test \Te@st}
\def\testtwo{\Test \tESt \@Test \Te@st}

\regexpatchcmd*{\testone}
  {\cC.}
  {\c{stringify}\0}
  {}{}

\testone

\makeatother

\end{document}
```

The search expression `\cC` matches control sequences, so `\cC.` matches a single control sequence. Prefixing the control sequence with `\stringify` is easier than adding tokens before and after it.

Comment: The OP says that the whole thing is happening in a class when `@` is a letter. (See comment to my answer.) OP is currently redoing the MWE, I think.

Answer (score 2):

Do you just want to wrap everything in `\makeatletter` ... `\makeatother`? You need this if you're using `@` in macro names in a document, as opposed to a class or package file. (In class and package files, `@` is already a letter.) Without this, `\@Test` is the macro `\@` followed by the letters `Test` and `\Te@st` is the macro `\Te` followed by `@` followed by the letters `st`. When `@` is treated as a letter, however, `\@Test` is the macro `\@Test` and `\Te@st` is the single macro `\Te@st`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{regexpatch}
\tracingxpatches
\begin{document}
\makeatletter
\def\testone{test \Test \tESt \@Test \Te@st}
\def\testtwo{\Test \tESt \@Test \Te@st}
\regexpatchcmd*{\testone}{\c{[a-zA-Z@]*}}{\c{begingroup}\c{ttfamily}\c{string}\0\c{endgroup}}{}{}
\regexpatchcmd*{\testtwo}{\c{[a-zA-Z@]*}}{\c{begingroup}\c{ttfamily}\c{string}\0\c{endgroup}}{}{}
\makeatother
\show\testone
\show\testtwo
\testone -- \testtwo
\end{document}
```

[image: result]

Comment: My mistake of not adding `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` was only at the MWE. All this stuff is on a class, so no catcode change on `@` is necessary. The behavior in the class is the same I exposed here, so I'll reformulate the MWE! Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @cfr and @egreg for their clarifications I've fixed the problem in the real situation before mentioned. I did it before writing this new MWE showing basically what @cfr and @egreg pointed, i.e. also the `\regexpatch` must be executed when with `@` being a letter.

Yesterday I wrote that this situation happens from a code inside a class; I was wrong. The situation shown in the MWE happens in the documentation part of a `.dtx`, then `@` is not a letter and `\makeatletter` is indeed required. The new MWE is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{regexpatch,catchfilebetweentags}

\newcommand{\stringify}[1]{\texttt{\string#1}}
\newcommand{\catch}{
 \catcode`\<=12
 \catcode`\>=12
 \makeatletter
 \CatchFileBetweenDelims{\testone}{test}{<}{>}[\catcode13=14\makeatletter]
 \regexpatchcmd*{\testone}{\cC.}{\c{stringify}\0}{}{}
 \makeatother
 \catcode`\<=13
 \catcode`\>=13
}

\begin{document}
 \catch
 \testone
\end{document}
```

Contents of file `test` is for example:

```
<
\Test
\@Test
\Te@st
>
```

Naturally, for the purpose of MWE I've replaced `\CatchFileBetweenDelims` to the testing definitions with `\def` (mistakenly without `\makeatletter`). The optional argument of this macro is intended to be some "starting" code like catcode change. When not specified this optional argument, the default is like it were `\makeatletter`. I've specified this optional argument not taking into account that the default `\makeatletter` was overridden and is required to be specified there (like in this new MWE).

I didn't try with `\makeatletter` before the patching command and that's another important fix that let me finish the `dtx` and submit a new version.

I wrote this answer for completeness but with yours were sufficient. Thanks again @cfr and @egreg.